# If $J[f]$ is strictly convex in $f$, are the minima of $J[<h, h>]$ w.r.t. $h$ the same up to rotations?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the strictly convex optimization problem
\begin{equation}
    (1)\quad\quad\min_{f} J[f]
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a differentiable mapping $\mathbb{S}^N\times \mathbb{S}^N \to\mathbb{R}$ and $J$ is differentiable. Without further constraints, given the strong convexity of $J$, there is a unique minimizer $f^{*}$. Now suppose that $f$ needs to have the form
$$
  f(x, y) = h(x)^T h(y)
$$
where $x, y\in\mathbb{S}^N$ and $h: \mathbb{S}^N \to\mathbb{S}^N$. This turns (1) into an optimization problem over $h$,
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:hopt}
    \min_{h} J[h].
\end{equation}

**Question:** Is it true that, if $h^{*}$ is a local minimizer of $J[h]$, then any other minimum $h'$ must have the form $h' = Rh^{*}$ for some rotation $R$?

Comment: The convexity of $J$ neither yields existence nor uniqueness of minimizers (even for the original problem). Do you have further properties of $J$?

Comment: Good point, thanks! I restricted the domain and image to the hypersphere $\mathcal{S}^N$ (so we are optimizing over a closed and bounded set) and we can require that $J$ is differentiable. Then a unique minimizer exists, right?

Comment: Not if $J$ is linear around $f^\ast$. You may want to have strict convexity of $J$.

Comment: Ok, right - J is actually strictly convex.